# How to check if value contains at least one character, expect for space

Tags: javascript, regex

I`m building messaging app and I need regex or some other way to validate message that user is about to send. Message must contain at least one character, expect for space.

```
const valid = *regex*

const message_a = "Hello, Jim!";
const message_b = " ";
const message_c = "      ";

valid.test(message_a) === **true**
valid.test(message_b) === **false**
valid.test(message_c) === **false**
```

I don't know how to make regex, so I just searched for such regex and found none. So I'm really looking forward for your answers, thanks!

Comment: How about `message.trim().length > 0`?

Comment: `[^ ]` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go the regex route, simply match on `\S`:

```js
var input = "Hello, Jim!";
if (/\S/.test(input)) {
    console.log("MATCH");
}
```

The pattern `/\S/` will match any single non whitespace character, anywhere in the input.

Comment: Question seems to specifically ask for excluding spaces, not any white-space character

Comment: Then we can use `[^ ]`, but I would expect that tab should also be included.